# How can I change the initial value on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For example I have an initial value of 10,000 when I click the radio button which is "Minus" and I enter a value of 1000 the initial value will become 9000. And when I click the radio button "Add" and I enter a value of 2000
current initial which is 9000 + 2000 is equal to 11,000.

The problem is the initialValue back to it's original value which is 10,000.

```js
//external script
function Compute(initialNum, numOne) {
    this._initialNum = initialNum;
    this._numOne = numOne;

    this.addNum = function() {
        alert(this._initialNum = this._initialNum + this._numOne);
        return this._initialNum;
    };

    this.minusNum = function() {
        alert(this._initialNum = this._initialNum - this._numOne);
        return this._initialNum;
    };
}

//body script
var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");

function printResult() {
    var initialValue = 10000, deposit = 0, withdraws = 0;
    var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
    var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
    var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
    var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);

    if (rdoAdd.checked) {
        deposit += objAccount.addNum(); 
        display = "<tr>";
     display += "<td>" + deposit + "</td>";
     display += "<tr>";
        tblResult.innerHTML += display;

        resetx();

    } else {
        withdraws += objAccount.minusNum();
        display = "<tr>";
     display += "<td>" + withdraws + "</td>";
     display += "<tr>";
        tblResult.innerHTML += display;

        resetx();
    }
}

function resetx() {
    document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value = "";
    document.getElementById("rdoAdd").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("rdoMinus").checked = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="rdoAdd" name="rdo" required>Add<br><br>
<input type="radio" id="rdoMinus" name="rdo" reuired>Minus<br><br>
<input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br><br>

<!-- 
     Withdraw<br><br>
     <input type="text" id="txtNumTwo"> 
-->

<button onclick="printResult()">Compute</button><br><br>

<table border="1px">
<th>Result</th>

<tbody id = "tblResult">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move

```
 var initialValue = 10000;
 var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue);
```

outside of the `printResult` function.

Comment: the result is NaN and how about the numOne parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a scope related issue. If you use `var` inside the function, it'll redeclare or create a new instance of `initialValue` in **local scope**.

If you want to change the value of variable `initialValue`, then don't use `var`. This will only change the variable defined in the **global scope**...

This works since the JavaScript interpreter firstly checks if there is an instance of the given variable in the local scope or not. If not, then it will check the existence of the variable in global scope.

**EDIT :**

As per your problem, you want the value of `initialValue` to persist after each calculation. In order to achieve this, you must first declare the object `objAccount` in the global scope outside the `printResult()` function; since in the code, every time the function `printValue()` is called, a new instance of `Compute` (`objAccount`) is being created. Secondly, you should remove the `numOne` attribute from `Compute` class and instead pass `numOne` as a parameter to `addNum()` and `minusNum()`.

You can modify the methods of `Compute` as:

```
this.addNum = function(_numOne) {
    ...
}

this.minusNum = function(_numOne) {
    ...
}
```

And while calling the methods,

```
objAccount.addNum(<some_number>);
```

and

```
objAccount.minusNum(<some_number>);
```

After this, you need not even use `deposit` or `withdraws`...

```
if (rdoAdd.checked) {
    objAccount.minusNum(numOne);    // This will directly adjust `initialValue`
    display = "<tr>";
    display += "<td>" + objAccount._initialNum + "</td>";
    display += "<tr>";
    tblResult.innerHTML += display;

    resetx();
}
```

Similarly, do the same with the `else` statement...

**Bonus:** You seem to be using `ES5` style, instead use `ES6` (includes keywords like `class` & `let`: similar to `var`)

#### Here's a snippet (using `ES6 classes`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" id="rdoAdd" name="rdo" required>Add<br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="rdoMinus" name="rdo" reuired>Minus<br><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br><br>

    <button onclick="printResult()">Compute</button><br><br>

    <table border="1px">
    <th>Result</th>

    <tbody id = "tblResult">

    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src = "java.js"></script>
    <script>
        class Compute {
            constructor(initialNum) {
                this._initialNum = initialNum;
            }

            addNum(_numOne) {
                alert(this._initialNum += _numOne);
                return this._initialNum;
            };

            minusNum(_numOne) {
                alert(this._initialNum -= _numOne);
                return this._initialNum;
            };
        }

        var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
        var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
        var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");
        var initialValue = 10000;
        var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue);
    
        function printResult() {
            var display = "";
            var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
            var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
            var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
    
            if (rdoAdd.checked) {
                objAccount.addNum(numOne);    // This will directly adjust `initialValue`
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + objAccount._initialNum + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
    
                resetx();

                } else {
                objAccount.minusNum(numOne);    // This will directly adjust `initialValue`
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + objAccount._initialNum + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
    
                resetx();
                }
        }

        function resetx() {
            document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value = "";
            document.getElementById("rdoAdd").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("rdoMinus").checked = false;
        }
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I declared the the initialValue outside the function nothing change when I add a number to initialValue the result is fine bu the problem is when I add another value to initialValue. The initialValue is back to 10,000

Comment: 1000 + 100 = the initialValue is 1100 when I add another 100 the initial value back to it's original value which is 10,000 so the answer will be the same

Comment: Can post a little code snippet for how you did that?

Comment: `var initialValue = 10000;
function printResult() {
var display = "";`

Comment: Did you replace `var initialValue = ...` by `initialValue = ...`?

Comment: No, I just put `var initialValue = 10000;` outside the function

Comment: @SwimmingPool Do you want to change the value of `initialValue` after each run? Ex: If you type 1000, this will give the output as 11000 (10000 + 1000), right; so, do you want to replace the `initialValue` by 11000? Is that what you want?

Comment: is that's right what should I do to make it happen?

Comment: @SwimmingPool I have posted a solution to your problem. Check it out, if it works...

Comment: it's work fine sir, but the only problem is the table row show undefined?

Comment: The problem was occurring because the script was trying to read `_initialValue` attribute instead of `_initialNum` attribute of the `Compute` class which didn't exist... My mistake `;)`. I have posted a snippet which just works. Check it out...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" id="rdoAdd" name="rdo" required>Add<br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="rdoMinus" name="rdo" reuired>Minus<br><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br><br>

    <button onclick="printResult()">Compute</button><br><br>

    <table border="1px">
    <th>Result</th>

    <tbody id = "tblResult">

    </tbody>
    </table>
<script src = "java.js"></script>
<script>
    var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
    var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
    var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");
    var initialValue = 10000;
    var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue);

function printResult() {
    var display = "";
    var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
    var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
    var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);

    if (rdoAdd.checked) {
    objAccount.addNum(numOne);    // This will directly adjust `initialValue`
    display = "<tr>";
    display += "<td>" + objAccount._initialValue + "</td>";
    display += "<tr>";
    tblResult.innerHTML += display;

    resetx();
    } else {
    objAccount.minusNum(numOne);    // This will directly adjust `initialValue`
    display = "<tr>";
    display += "<td>" + objAccount._initialValue + "</td>";
    display += "<tr>";
    tblResult.innerHTML += display;

    resetx();
    }
}
function resetx() {
    document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value = "";
    document.getElementById("rdoAdd").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("rdoMinus").checked = false;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `Compute` function / class?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Compute(initialNum) {
    this._initialNum = initialNum;

    this.addNum = function(numOne) {
        alert(this._initialNum = this._initialNum + numOne);
        return this._initialNum;
    };

    this.minusNum = function(numOne) {
        alert(this._initialNum = this._initialNum - numOne);
        return this._initialNum;
    };
}
```